# Clojure won't spit to results.txt

Tags: clojure, io

Edit now I get :  Unable to resolve symbol: thecount in this context, compiling:(C:\Users\Matthew.lein\bin\testingproj\src\testingproj\core.clj:14:1)

With the following code

```
(defn countstarter [] (let [thecount 0] thecount))
(defn i++ [] (inc thecount))
(defn linetravel [aline thecount]
(nth (split aline #"\s+") (thecount) "nothing found")
)

(defn grammarCHECK [aline  thecount]
(countstarter)
(while (not= linetravel "nothing found")
(do
     (print thecount) (print "debugging function")
  (if (isAFactor linetravel)
         (if (isOpenParen linetravel)
           (isAExpression  linetravel) true)
  false);;know it is not a factor if here




(i++)

)
))
```

I am running

```
(with-open [r (io/reader "input.txt")]
 (doseq [line (line-seq r)]
  (spit "results.txt"  (grammarCHECK line thecount))
  (spit "output.txt" (str (join "\n" (split line #"\s+")) "\n") :append true)

))
```

It works fine if I comment out `(spit "results.txt"  (grammarCHECK line))`

but has the following stack when ran with it, and I have no idea why...

[image]

Comment: please don't add screenshots for error messages/traces.  just paste them into the question as code. that makes them easier to read and searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at line `(i++)` you are trying to invoke the Long you defined the line before

## Edit

I was trying to first give you a hint.. :)

You should know that clojure doesnt use state the same way that java-like languages do.. when you run `(i++)`, it gets evaluated into `(inc thecount)`, which sees the long defined somewhere (hopefully). Although this might return the desired new Long value, it wouldnt update the original copy of the variable, `thecount`. This variable doesnt really exist because the line `(countstarter)` had no effect for the same reason.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

If you want to have a loop with some state, you could use something like the following, which is not very clojure-like, rather it resembles java-like coding style:

```
(loop [state1 0 state2 1]
  (when (< state1 10)
    (println state1 state2)
    (recur (inc state1) (* 2 state2)))
```

You should try out something like [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/), it will help you get used to the way code is written in a lisp-like language

Comment: Can you elaborate, I moved `def i++ (inc thge count)` and made it defn

Comment: Your answer is a step in the right direction, but it is only a step, not an answer.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97810/i-need-help-with-clojure-stuck-and-project-is-due-tonight

If you are still around